# Legend Overlapping in graph plotting area

Tags: python, pandas, legend, seaborn

I have a dataframe as below (obtained after lot of preprocessing)

Please find dataframe

```
d = {'token': {361: '180816_031', 119: '180816_031', 101: '180816_031', 135: '180816_031', 292: '180816_031',
           133: '180816_031', 99: '180816_031', 270: '180816_031', 19: '180816_031', 382: '180816_031',
           414: '180816_031', 267: '180816_031', 218: '180816_031', 398: '180816_031', 287: '180816_031',
           155: '180816_031', 392: '180816_031', 265: '180816_031', 239: '180816_031', 237: '180816_031'},
 'station': {361: 'deneb', 119: 'callisto', 101: 'callisto', 135: 'callisto', 292: 'callisto', 133: 'deneb',
             99: 'callisto', 270: 'callisto', 19: 'deneb', 382: 'callisto', 414: 'deneb', 267: 'callisto',
             218: 'deneb', 398: 'callisto', 287: 'deneb', 155: 'deneb', 392: 'deneb', 265: 'callisto',
             239: 'callisto', 237: 'callisto'},
 'cycle_number': {361: 'cycle09', 119: 'cycle06', 101: 'cycle04', 135: 'cycle01', 292: 'cycle04', 133: 'cycle05',
                  99: 'cycle06', 270: 'cycle07', 19: 'cycle04', 382: 'cycle08', 414: 'cycle04', 267: 'cycle10',
                  218: 'cycle07', 398: 'cycle08', 287: 'cycle09', 155: 'cycle08', 392: 'cycle06', 265: 'cycle02',
                  239: 'cycle09', 237: 'cycle07'},
 'variable': {361: 'adj_high_quality_reads', 119: 'short_pass', 101: 'short_pass', 135: 'cell_mask_bilayers_sum',
              292: 'adj_active_polymerase', 133: 'cell_mask_bilayers_sum', 99: 'short_pass',
              270: 'adj_active_polymerase', 19: 'Unnamed: 0', 382: 'adj_high_quality_reads',
              414: 'num_align_high_quality_reads', 267: 'adj_active_polymerase', 218: 'adj_single_pores',
              398: 'num_align_high_quality_reads', 287: 'adj_active_polymerase', 155: 'cell_mask_bilayers_sum',
              392: 'num_align_high_quality_reads', 265: 'adj_active_polymerase', 239: 'adj_single_pores',
              237: 'adj_single_pores'},
 'value': {361: 99704.0, 119: 2072785.0, 101: 2061059.0, 135: 1682208.0, 292: 675306.0, 133: 1714292.0,
           99: 2072785.0, 270: 687988.0, 19: 19.0, 382: np.nan, 414: 285176.0, 267: 86914.0, 218: 948971.0,
           398: 405196.0, 287: 137926.0, 155: 1830032.0, 392: 480081.0, 265: 951689.0, 239: 681452.0,
           237: 882671.0}}
```

**Data:**

```
          token   station cycle_number                      variable  \
19   180816_031     deneb      cycle04                    Unnamed: 0   
99   180816_031  callisto      cycle06                    short_pass   
101  180816_031  callisto      cycle04                    short_pass   
119  180816_031  callisto      cycle06                    short_pass   
133  180816_031     deneb      cycle05        cell_mask_bilayers_sum   
135  180816_031  callisto      cycle01        cell_mask_bilayers_sum   
155  180816_031     deneb      cycle08        cell_mask_bilayers_sum   
218  180816_031     deneb      cycle07              adj_single_pores   
237  180816_031  callisto      cycle07              adj_single_pores   
239  180816_031  callisto      cycle09              adj_single_pores   
265  180816_031  callisto      cycle02         adj_active_polymerase   
267  180816_031  callisto      cycle10         adj_active_polymerase   
270  180816_031  callisto      cycle07         adj_active_polymerase   
287  180816_031     deneb      cycle09         adj_active_polymerase   
292  180816_031  callisto      cycle04         adj_active_polymerase   
361  180816_031     deneb      cycle09        adj_high_quality_reads   
382  180816_031  callisto      cycle08        adj_high_quality_reads   
392  180816_031     deneb      cycle06  num_align_high_quality_reads   
398  180816_031  callisto      cycle08  num_align_high_quality_reads   
414  180816_031     deneb      cycle04  num_align_high_quality_reads   

         value  
19        19.0  
99   2072785.0  
101  2061059.0  
119  2072785.0  
133  1714292.0  
135  1682208.0  
155  1830032.0  
218   948971.0  
237   882671.0  
239   681452.0  
265   951689.0  
267    86914.0  
270   687988.0  
287   137926.0  
292   675306.0  
361    99704.0  
382        NaN  
392   480081.0  
398   405196.0  
414   285176.0
```

I am trying to create scatterplot with smooth line (Expected Output below)

[image: Expected Output]

I am using below code (with help) to replicate the same, however I am having my legend values overlapped in the plotting area.[image: OUTPUT PRODUCED using my code]

Code Used to produce Output

```
df['cycle_number'] = df['cycle_number'].str.replace('cycle', '')
df['cycle_number'] = df['cycle_number'].apply(pd.to_numeric)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 4)
# sns.pointplot('cycle_number', 'value', data=df, hue='variable', err_style="bars", ci=68)
g2=sns.lmplot('cycle_number', 'value', data=df, hue='variable', ci=2, order=5, truncate=True)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
#ax.legend(loc='right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.1))
ax.legend(loc='left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0))
for p in ax.patches:
             ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='gray', xytext=(0, 20),
                 textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

Please help to remove the overlapped legend from plotting area

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, I saw that question & have utlized the learning from most popular answer (check the code ax.set_position), however it does not seem to work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
ax.legend(loc='left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0))
```

by

```
ax.legend(loc=(1.05, 0.2))
```

You can modify the positions `(1.05, 0.2)` as per your desired location. The values here are in fractions.

[image]

Comment: Did you comment out the following line `ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])`?

Comment: Yes, I did ran both with comment out that & without commenting that. However, the output did not change. still overlapping

Comment: I get a completely different plot than yours but at least the legend is placed outside the plot in my case

Comment: Can you please share the output which you are getting

Comment: Comment the following two lines: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and `fig.set_size_inches(16, 4)`. I shared my output

Comment: If I comment those two lines then I get error NameError: name 'ax' is not defined.
I am sorry can you please share the code that you are running,